# Pythonic way to vectorize double summation

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, vectorization

I'm attempting to convert a double summation formula into code, but can't figure out the correct matrix/vector representation of it.

The first summation is i to n, and the second is over j > i to n.

I'm guessing there is a much more efficient & pythonic way of writing this?

I resorted to nested for loops to just get it working but, as expected, it runs very slowly with a large dataset:

```py
def wapc_denom(weights, vols):
    x = []
    y = []

    for i, wi in enumerate(weights):
        for j, wj in enumerate(weights):
            if j > i:
                x.append(wi * wj * vols[i] * vols[j])
        y.append(np.sum(x))

    return np.sum(y)
```

Edit:

Using guidance from smci's answer I think I have a potential solution:

```py
def wapc_denom2(weights, vols):
    return np.sum(np.tril(np.outer(weights, vols.T)**2, k=-1))
```

Comment: What are the shapes of `weights` and `vols`?

Comment: They're both 1D vectors of same length

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want to count every term only once (for that you have to move the `x = []` into the outer loop) one cheap way of computing the sum would be

Create mock data

```
weights = np.random.random(10)
vols = np.random.random(10)
```

Do the calculation

```
wv = weights * vols
result = (wv.sum()**2 - wv@wv) / 2
```

Check that it's the same

```
def wapc_denom(weights, vols):
    y = []

    for i, wi in enumerate(weights):
        x = []
        for j, wj in enumerate(weights):
            if j > i:
                x.append(wi * wj * vols[i] * vols[j])
        y.append(np.sum(x))

    return np.sum(y)

assert np.allclose(result, wapc_denom(weights, vols))
```

Why does it work?

What we are doing is compute the sum of the full matrix, subtract the diagonal and divide by two. This is cheap because it is easy to verify that the sum of an outer product is just the product of the summed factors.

Answer (score 1):

- `wi * wj * vols[i] * vols[j]` is a telltale. `vols` is another vector, so first you want to compute the vector `wv = w * vols`
- then `(wj * vols[j]) * (wi * vols[i])` = `wv^T * wv` is your (matrix outer product) expression; that's a column vector * a row vector. But actually you only want the sum. So I don't see a need to construct a vector `y.append(np.sum(x))`, you're only going to sum it anyway `np.sum(y)`
- also the `if j > i` part means you only want the sum of the Lower Triangular part, and exclude the diagonal.

  - EDIT: the result is fully determined just from wv, I didn't think we needed the matrix to get the sum, and we didn't need the diagonal; @PaulPanzer found the most compact expression.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's probably the `j > i` part that's throwing me off. Though is the `wv^T * wv` expression not a multiplication of 2 vector dot products (so no matrix)? Would it be some sort of constrained dot product where only some of the terms are used for the `j > i` part?

Comment: By `wv^T * wv` I mean the *column* vector multiplied by the *row* vector, hence the output is a matrix. It's not a dot-product; that would be  `wv * wv^T`. But anyway you're only interested in the LT off-diagonal sum of `wv^T * wv`. You can certainly formulate this as numpy vector or matrix operations rather than nested loops, and you don't need indices, that's only for the LT off-diagonal part.

Comment: Thanks, so that would be the outer product that's needed? I think I've got a potential solution added as an edit. Look reasonable?

Comment: But since it's fully determined just from `wv`, I didn't think we needed the matrix to get the sum, and I pointed out we didn't need the diagonal; @PaulPanzer found the most compact expression.

Answer (score 0):

You can use triangulations in numpy, check `np.triu` and `np.meshgrid`. Do:

```
np.product(np.triu(np.meshgrid(weights,weights), 1) * np.triu(np.meshgrid(vols,vols), 1),0).sum(1).cumsum().sum()
```

Example:

```
w = np.arange(4) +1
v = np.array([1,3,2,2])
print(np.triu(np.meshgrid(w,w), k=1))
>>array([[[0, 2, 3, 4],
        [0, 0, 3, 4],
        [0, 0, 0, 4],
        [0, 0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 1, 1, 1],
        [0, 0, 2, 2],
        [0, 0, 0, 3],
        [0, 0, 0, 0]]])

# example of product + triu + meshgrid (your x values):
print(np.product(np.triu(np.meshgrid(w,w), 1) * np.triu(np.meshgrid(v,v), 1),0))
>>array([[ 0,  6,  6,  8],
   [ 0,  0, 36, 48],
   [ 0,  0,  0, 48],
   [ 0,  0,  0,  0]])

print(np.product(np.triu(np.meshgrid(w,w), 1) * np.triu(np.meshgrid(v,v), 1),0).sum(1).cumsum().sum())
>> 428
print(wapc_denom(w, v))
>> 428
```